# How to know if any images were captured by the grDevices:png function?

Tags: r

I have the following code to capture images to my device

```
png(filename="G:\\temp\\Images1\\Image%04d.png")
```

and then i do `dev.off()` at the end of my script

It works perfectly as long as i have code in the script that creates/outputs image(s).

But if my script does not  contain any image plotting code , i still get a blank image(the default one which is created when i run the png function) in the specified folder .

Is there a way to not add the default image or delete it if the code does not output any image

For ex for the following script

```
png(filename="G:\\temp\\Images1\\Image%04d.png") 
x<- 2+ 3 
dev.off()
```

After dev.off() , is it possible to not have any images in the specified folder , or is there a way to know if the default image was overwritten at all

Comment: behaviour might be platform-specific; on my system the blank file doesn't seem to get created at all. Perhaps it will be zero-length, and you can use `file.info()` to find out?

Comment: The size can be 0 for really small images as well , for ex plot(1) also returns a size of 0 .

Comment: not for me: on Ubuntu 12.04 `file.info("foo.png")$size` is 3733. Even `plot(1,axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE,type="n")` generates a 318-byte file.

Comment: yeah my bad...the default image(when there is no image code) returns size of 318 and plot(1) returns 1696. Still i can't differentiate

Comment: can't you just say that (1) non-existent file or (2) size<=318 implies no actual plot was created?

Comment: 1) non-existent file will never happen because there is always a default file
2) i am not sure if size<=318 is a guarantee of the fact that no image was created . There has to be a better way , right?

Comment: that, and checking time stamps, is all I've got.